# R Shiny checkboxGroupInput, displaying text of options as web links

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get checkboxGroupInput to display the text next to the check boxes as links.  I would like each of the options 1, 2, & 3 to link to a separate webpage, independent of whether or not the boxes are checked.  Here is my failed ui.r code:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  h3("User Options"),
  checkboxGroupInput("options",
                     label = h6("Select options"),
                     choices = list(
                       a("option 1",href = "http://www.option1.com") = "option_1",
                       a("option 2",href = "http://www.option2.com") = "option_2",
                       a("option 3",href = "http://www.option3.com") = "option_3"
                     ))                              
    ), #end sidebar Panel    
mainPanel("other stuff"              
    ) #end mainPanel       
) #end sidebarLayout        
) #end fluidPage
) #end ShinyUI
```

And the corresponding server.r code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){})
```

The error that I'm receiving is:

```
Error in parse(text = lines, srcfile = srcfile) : 
C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/test/ui.R:12:74: unexpected '='
11:                          choices = list(
12:                            a("option 1",href = "http://www.option1.com") =
                                                                            ^
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a() to display my links.  Is there another way to do this that would work, or is this something that can't be done with shiny.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Jeff